# How to set properties for dynamic text?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have dynamic textboxes which is included in the movieclip button. I set the text like this :  `buttonA.label_txt.text`. However when the button was hit, the color of the button changed based on what I've set but the text is missing.

I already check the properties of the textbox and already make sure the color was black, as it was supposed to be. But it still missing.

Here is the code:

```
var _list:Array = ["XXXquestionsXXX"];
var _marks:Array = [];
var i:int;
var myscore = 0;

question_txt.text = _list[0];

buttonA.label_txt.text = "A. Chicken";

buttonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);

function q1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  if(event.currentTarget == buttonA)
  {
      _marks.push(" A. chicken /" + "Correct");

      var SelColor1:Number = 0XFFFF0;
      var myColorTransform1 = new ColorTransform();
      myColorTransform1.color = SelColor1;
      buttonA.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform1; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the color of a movie clip (or any `DisplayObjectContainer`) using a `ColorTransform` it will affect *all the contents* of the object, so in your case the text becomes colored the same as the background and you can't see it. To color just the background of your button you need to apply the `transform` to a background object in your button, such as:

```
myButton.background_mc.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
```

Or possibly:

```
myButton.getChildAt(0).transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
```

Comment: I dont have any background object in my button. I just create one rectangle and convert it as movieclip. However, I tried to add a small rect inside the button as background and apply the first suggestion. Nothing works. Then I tried to change and used the second coding, the border of the button changed when cursor hit it, but error appeared #Error1006: getChildat is not a function. Why?

Comment: I figure out the problem. Turn out the first choice is working, for me. But, the box color remains on the next frame. It was supposed to turn back to normal..

Comment: It won't turn back to normal atuomagically. To turn back to normal reset the color transform: `transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform()`